# How to add scroll bar to the table body using DataTables plugin?

Tags: javascript

I am using dataTables plugin to show my data in table, but when I add scroll bar to the table body, table header looks like this:

[image: datatable header]

I found solution in Datatable documentation they suggest to add 2 lines

```
$(".dataTables_scrollHeadInner").css({"width":"100%"});
$(".table ").css({"width":"100%"});
```

but when I add these two lines in javascript, the table alignment looks bad. How can I add a scroll bar to the datatable body?

JavaScript:

```
$('#protein-table').DataTable({
    scrollY:'400px',
    scrollCollapse:true,
    ordering: false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#protein-table').DataTable( {
        "scrollY": "400px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging":false
    })
});
//try this code
```